# Silex + Couchdb + DoctrineCouchDbODM

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, couchdb, silex

Merry Christmas all.

I'm trying to use the doctrine couchdb-ODM with a silex php project. I already got it working with doctrine-orm but with couch, it keeps breaking.

I've searched the web for days but nothing. I'll be specific, I keep getting this funny error

`Class Package\documents\User is not a valid document or mapped super class.`

On debugging, I noticed this call in Doctrine/ODM/CouchDB/Mapping/Driver/AnnotationDriver.php line 55

`$classAnnotations = $this->reader->getClassAnnotations($reflClass);`

Returns an empty array. I guess there maybe something wrong with my configuration, but can't seem to point it out.

Any help will be appreciated.

Update
To configure CouchDB ODM. I created 2 service providers. 1 for CouchDB and the other for CouchDB ODM, modeled after the the default `DoctrineServiceProvider` in Silex

### The CouchDB Service Provider

```
<?php

namespace Package\services\Doctrine\CouchDB;

use Pimple\Container;
use Pimple\ServiceProviderInterface;

use Doctrine\CouchDB\CouchDBClient;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Configuration;
use Doctrine\Common\EventManager;
use Doctrine\CouchDB\HTTP\SocketClient;

use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Logger\DbalLogger;

class DoctrineCouchDbServiceProvider implements ServiceProviderInterface {
    /**
    * Registers services on the given app.
    *
    * This method should only be used to configure services and parameters.
    * It should not get services.
    *
    * @param Application $container An Application instance
    */
    public function register(Container $container) {
        $container['couchdb.default_options'] = [
            'type' => 'socket',
            'host' => 'localhost',
            'port' => 5984,
            'user' => null,
            'password' => null,
            'ip' => null,
            'logging' => true
        ];

        $container['couchdbs.options.initializer'] = $container->protect(function () use ($container) {
            static $initialized = false;

            if ($initialized) {
                return;
            }

            $initialized = true;

            if (!isset($container['couchdbs.options'])) {
                $container['couchdbs.options'] = [
                'default' => isset($container['couchdb.options']) ? $container['couchdb.options'] : []
                ];
            }

            $tmp = $container['couchdbs.options'];
            foreach ($tmp as $name => &$options) {
                $options = array_replace_recursive($container['couchdb.default_options'], $options);

                if (!isset($container['couchdbs.default'])) {
                    $container['couchdbs.default'] = $name;
                }
            }
            $container['couchdbs.options'] = $tmp;
        });

        $container['couchdbs'] = function($container) {
            $container['couchdbs.options.initializer']();

            $couchdbs = new Container();
            foreach ($container['couchdbs.options'] as $name => $options) {
                if ($container['couchdbs.default'] === $name) {
                    // we use shortcuts here in case the default has been overridden
                    $config = $container['couchdb.config'];
                    $manager = $container['couchdb.event_manager'];
                } else {
                    $config = $container['couchdbs.config'][$name];
                    $manager = $container['couchdbs.event_manager'][$name];
                }

                $couchdbs[$name] = function () use ($options, $config, $manager) {
                    return CouchDBClient::create($options);
                };
            }

            return $couchdbs;
        };

        $container['couchdbs.config'] = function ($container) {
            $container['couchdbs.options.initializer']();

            $configs = new Container();
            $addLogger = isset($container['logger']) && null !== $container['logger'] && class_exists('Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Logger\DbalLogger');
            foreach ($container['couchdbs.options'] as $name => $options) {
                $configs[$name] = new Configuration();
                if ($addLogger) {
                    $configs[$name]->setSQLLogger(new DbalLogger($container['logger'], isset($container['stopwatch']) ? $container['stopwatch'] : null));
                }
            }
          return $configs;
        };

        $container['couchdbs.event_manager'] = function ($container) {
            $container['couchdbs.options.initializer']();

            $managers = new Container();
            foreach ($container['couchdbs.options'] as $name => $options) {
                $managers[$name] = new EventManager();
            }

            return $managers;
        };

        // shortcuts for the "first" DB
        $container['couchdb'] = function ($container) {
            $couchdbs = $container['couchdbs'];

            return $couchdbs[$container['couchdbs.default']];
        };

        $container['couchdb.config'] = function ($container) {
            $couchdbs = $container['couchdbs.config'];

            return $couchdbs[$container['couchdbs.default']];
        };

        $container['couchdb.event_manager'] = function ($container) {
            $couchdbs = $container['couchdbs.event_manager'];

            return $couchdbs[$container['couchdbs.default']];
        };
    }
}
```

### The CouchDB ODM Service Provider

```
<?php

namespace Package\services\Doctrine\CouchDB;

use Pimple\Container;
use Pimple\ServiceProviderInterface;

use Doctrine\Common\Cache\ApcCache;
use Doctrine\Common\Cache\ArrayCache;
use Doctrine\Common\Cache\CacheProvider;
use Doctrine\Common\Cache\CouchbaseCache;
use Doctrine\Common\Cache\FilesystemCache;
use Doctrine\Common\Cache\MemcacheCache;
use Doctrine\Common\Cache\MemcachedCache;
use Doctrine\Common\Cache\RedisCache;
use Doctrine\Common\Cache\XcacheCache;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\Driver\MappingDriver;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\Driver\MappingDriverChain;

use Doctrine\CouchDB\CouchDBClient;
use Doctrine\ODM\CouchDB\Configuration;
use Doctrine\ODM\CouchDB\DocumentManager;
use Doctrine\ODM\CouchDB\Mapping\Driver\DriverChain;
use Doctrine\ODM\CouchDB\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver;
use Doctrine\ODM\CouchDB\Mapping\Driver\PHPDriver;
use Doctrine\ODM\CouchDB\Mapping\Driver\XmlDriver;
use Doctrine\ODM\CouchDB\Mapping\Driver\YamlDriver;
use Doctrine\ODM\CouchDB\Types\Type;

class DoctrineCouchDbOdmServiceProvider implements ServiceProviderInterface {
    /**
    * Registers services on the given app.
    *
    * This method should only be used to configure services and parameters.
    * It should not get services.
    *
    * @param Application $container An Application instance
    */
    public function register(Container $container) {
        foreach ($this->getCouchDbOdmDefaults($container) as $key => $value) {
            if (!isset($container[$key])) {
                $container[$key] = $value;
            }
        }

        $container['couchdb.dm.default_options'] = [
            'connection' => 'default',
            'mappings' => [],
            'types' => [],
        ];

        $container['couchdb.dms.options.initializer'] = $container->protect(function () use ($container) {
            static $initialized = false;

            if ($initialized) {
                return;
            }

            $initialized = true;


            if (!isset($container['couchdb.dms.options'])) {
                $container['couchdb.dms.options'] = [
                    'default' => isset($container['couchdb.dm.options']) ? $container['couchdb.dm.options'] : []
                ];
            }

            $tmp = $container['couchdb.dms.options'];
            foreach ($tmp as $name => &$options) {
                $options = array_replace($container['couchdb.dm.default_options'], $options);

                if (!isset($container['couchdb.dms.default'])) {
                    $container['couchdb.dms.default'] = $name;
                }
            }
            $container['couchdb.dms.options'] = $tmp;
        });

        $container['couchdb.dm_name_from_param_key'] = $container->protect(function ($paramKey) use ($container) {
            $container['couchdb.dms.options.initializer']();

            if (isset($container[$paramKey])) {
                return $container[$paramKey];
            }

            return $container['couchdb.dms.default'];
        });

        $container['couchdb.dms'] = function($container) {
            $container['couchdb.dms.options.initializer']();

            $dms = new Container();
            foreach ($container['couchdb.dms.options'] as $name => $options) {
                if ($container['couchdb.dms.default'] === $name) {
                // we use shortcuts here in case the default has been overridden
                $config = $container['couchdb.dm.config'];
                } else {
                    $config = $container['couchdb.dms.config'][$name];
                }

                if (isset($options['dbname'])) {
                    $config->setDefaultDB($options['dbname']);
                }

                // print_r($options);
                $dms[$name] = function ($dms) use ($container, $options, $config) {
                    $httpClient = new \Doctrine\CouchDB\HTTP\SocketClient();
                    $dm = DocumentManager::create(
                        CouchDBClient::create($container['couchdb.options']),
                        $config,
                        $container['couchdbs.event_manager'][$options['connection']]
                    );

                    return $dm;
                };
            }

            return $dms;
        };

        $container['couchdb.dms.config'] = function($container) {
            $container['couchdb.dms.options.initializer']();

            $configs = new Container();
            foreach ($container['couchdb.dms.options'] as $name => $options) {
                $config = new Configuration;

                $container['couchdb.cache.configurer']($name, $config, $options);

                $config->setProxyDir($container['couchdb.proxies_dir']);
                $config->setProxyNamespace($container['couchdb.proxies_namespace']);
                $config->setAutoGenerateProxyClasses($container['couchdb.auto_generate_proxies']);
                $config->setValidateDoctrineMetadata($container['couchdb.validate_doctrine_metadata']);
                $config->setAllOrNothingFlush($container['couchdb.all_or_nothing_flush']);
                $config->setLuceneHandlerName('_fti');

                $chain = $container['couchdb.mapping_driver_chain.locator']($name);
                foreach ((array) $options['mappings'] as $document) {
                    if (!is_array($document)) {
                        throw new \InvalidArgumentException(
                    "The 'couchdb.dm.options' option 'mappings' should be an array of arrays."
                        );
                    }

                    if (!empty($document['resources_namespace'])) {
                        $document['path'] = $container['psr0_resource_locator']->findFirstDirectory($document['resources_namespace']);
                    }

                    if (isset($document['alias'])) {
                        $config->addDocumentNamespace($document['alias'], $document['namespace']);
                    }

                    switch ($document['type']) {
                        case 'annotation':
                            $useSimpleAnnotationReader =
                            isset($document['use_simple_annotation_reader'])
                            ? $document['use_simple_annotation_reader']
                            : true;
                            $driver = $config->newDefaultAnnotationDriver((array) $document['path'], $useSimpleAnnotationReader);
                            $chain->addDriver($driver, $document['namespace']);
                            break;
                        case 'annotation2':
                            $driver = new AnnotationDriver($document['path']);
                            $chain->addDriver($driver, $document['namespace']);
                            break;
                        case 'yml':
                            $driver = new YamlDriver($document['path']);
                            $chain->addDriver($driver, $document['namespace']);
                            break;
                        case 'xml':
                            $driver = new XmlDriver($document['path']);
                            $chain->addDriver($driver, $document['namespace']);
                            break;
                        case 'php':
                            $driver = new PHPDriver($document['path']);
                            $chain->addDriver($driver, $document['namespace']);
                            break;
                        default:
                            throw new \InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('"%s" is not a recognized driver', $document['type']));
                            break;
                    }
                }
                $config->setMetadataDriverImpl($chain);

                foreach ((array) $options['types'] as $typeName => $typeClass) {
                    if (Type::hasType($typeName)) {
                        Type::overrideType($typeName, $typeClass);
                    } else {
                        Type::addType($typeName, $typeClass);
                    }
                }
                $configs[$name] = $config;
            }
            return $configs;
        };

        $container['couchdb.cache.configurer'] = $container->protect(function ($name, Configuration $config, $options) use ($container) {
            $config->setMetadataCacheImpl($container['couchdb.cache.locator']($name, 'metadata', $options));
        });

        $container['couchdb.cache.locator'] = $container->protect(function ($name, $cacheName, $options) use ($container) {
            $cacheNameKey = $cacheName . '_cache';

            if (!isset($options[$cacheNameKey])) {
                $options[$cacheNameKey] = $container['couchdb.default_cache'];
            }

            if (isset($options[$cacheNameKey]) && !is_array($options[$cacheNameKey])) {
                $options[$cacheNameKey] = array(
                    'driver' => $options[$cacheNameKey],
                );
            } 

            if (!isset($options[$cacheNameKey]['driver'])) {
                throw new \RuntimeException("No driver specified for '$cacheName'");
            }

            $driver = $options[$cacheNameKey]['driver'];

            $cacheInstanceKey = 'couchdb.cache.instances.'.$name.'.'.$cacheName;
            if (isset($container[$cacheInstanceKey])) {
                return $container[$cacheInstanceKey];
            }

            $cache = $container['couchdb.cache.factory']($driver, $options[$cacheNameKey]);

            if (isset($options['cache_namespace']) && $cache instanceof CacheProvider) {
                $cache->setNamespace($options['cache_namespace']);
            }

            return $container[$cacheInstanceKey] = $cache;
        });

        $container['couchdb.cache.factory.backing_memcache'] = $container->protect(function () {
            return new \Memcache;
        });

        $container['couchdb.cache.factory.memcache'] = $container->protect(function ($cacheOptions) use ($container) {
            if (empty($cacheOptions['host']) || empty($cacheOptions['port'])) {
                throw new \RuntimeException('Host and port options need to be specified for memcache cache');
            }

            $memcache = $container['couchdb.cache.factory.backing_memcache']();
            $memcache->connect($cacheOptions['host'], $cacheOptions['port']);

            $cache = new MemcacheCache;
            $cache->setMemcache($memcache);

            return $cache;
        });

        $container['couchdb.cache.factory.backing_memcached'] = $container->protect(function () {
            return new \Memcached;
        });

        $container['couchdb.cache.factory.memcached'] = $container->protect(function ($cacheOptions) use ($container) {
            if (empty($cacheOptions['host']) || empty($cacheOptions['port'])) {
                throw new \RuntimeException('Host and port options need to be specified for memcached cache');
            }

            $memcached = $container['couchdb.cache.factory.backing_memcached']();
            $memcached->addServer($cacheOptions['host'], $cacheOptions['port']);

            $cache = new MemcachedCache;
            $cache->setMemcached($memcached);

            return $cache;
        });

        $container['couchdb.cache.factory.backing_memcached'] = $container->protect(function () {
            return new \Memcached;
        });

        $container['couchdb.cache.factory.memcached'] = $container->protect(function ($cacheOptions) use ($container) {
            if (empty($cacheOptions['host']) || empty($cacheOptions['port'])) {
                throw new \RuntimeException('Host and port options need to be specified for memcached cache');
            }

            /** @var \Memcached $memcached */
            $memcached = $container['couchdb.cache.factory.backing_memcached']();
            $memcached->addServer($cacheOptions['host'], $cacheOptions['port']);

            $cache = new MemcachedCache;
            $cache->setMemcached($memcached);

            return $cache;
        });

        $container['couchdb.cache.factory.backing_redis'] = $container->protect(function () {
            return new \Redis;
        });

        $container['couchdb.cache.factory.redis'] = $container->protect(function ($cacheOptions) use ($container) {
            if (empty($cacheOptions['host']) || empty($cacheOptions['port'])) {
                throw new \RuntimeException('Host and port options need to be specified for redis cache');
            }

            /** @var \Redis $redis */
            $redis = $container['couchdb.cache.factory.backing_redis']();
            $redis->connect($cacheOptions['host'], $cacheOptions['port']);

            if (isset($cacheOptions['password'])) {
                $redis->auth($cacheOptions['password']);
            }

            $cache = new RedisCache;
            $cache->setRedis($redis);

            return $cache;
        });

        $container['couchdb.cache.factory.array'] = $container->protect(function () {
            return new ArrayCache;
        });

        $container['couchdb.cache.factory.apc'] = $container->protect(function () {
            return new ApcCache;
        });

        $container['couchdb.cache.factory.xcache'] = $container->protect(function () {
            return new XcacheCache;
        });

        $container['couchdb.cache.factory.filesystem'] = $container->protect(function ($cacheOptions) {
            if (empty($cacheOptions['path'])) {
                throw new \RuntimeException('FilesystemCache path not defined');
            }

            $cacheOptions += array(
                'extension' => FilesystemCache::EXTENSION,
                'umask' => 0002,
            );

            return new FilesystemCache($cacheOptions['path'], $cacheOptions['extension'], $cacheOptions['umask']);
        });

        $container['couchdb.cache.factory.couchbase'] = $container->protect(function ($cacheOptions) {
            $host='';
            $bucketName='';
            $user='';
            $password='';
            if (empty($cacheOptions['host'])) {
                $host='127.0.0.1';
            }
            if (empty($cacheOptions['bucket'])) {
                $bucketName='default';
            }
            if (!empty($cacheOptions['user'])) {
                $user=$cacheOptions['user'];
            }
            if (!empty($cacheOptions['password'])) {
                $password=$cacheOptions['password'];
            }

            $couchbase = new \Couchbase($host,$user,$password,$bucketName);
            $cache = new CouchbaseCache();
            $cache->setCouchbase($couchbase);
            return $cache;
        });

        $container['couchdb.cache.factory'] = $container->protect(function ($driver, $cacheOptions) use ($container) {
            switch ($driver) {
                case 'array':
                    return $container['couchdb.cache.factory.array']();
                case 'apc':
                    return $container['couchdb.cache.factory.apc']();
                case 'xcache':
                    return $container['couchdb.cache.factory.xcache']();
                case 'memcache':
                    return $container['couchdb.cache.factory.memcache']($cacheOptions);
                case 'memcached':
                    return $container['couchdb.cache.factory.memcached']($cacheOptions);
                case 'filesystem':
                    return $container['couchdb.cache.factory.filesystem']($cacheOptions);
                case 'redis':
                    return $container['couchdb.cache.factory.redis']($cacheOptions);
                case 'couchbase':
                    return $container['couchdb.cache.factory.couchbase']($cacheOptions);
                default:
                    throw new \RuntimeException("Unsupported cache type '$driver' specified");
            }
        });

        $container['couchdb.mapping_driver_chain.locator'] = $container->protect(function ($name = null) use ($container) {
            $container['couchdb.dms.options.initializer']();

            if (null === $name) {
                $name = $container['couchdb.dms.default'];
            }

            $cacheInstanceKey = 'couchdb.mapping_driver_chain.instances.'.$name;
            if (isset($container[$cacheInstanceKey])) {
                return $container[$cacheInstanceKey];
            }

            return $container[$cacheInstanceKey] = $container['couchdb.mapping_driver_chain.factory']($name);
        });

        $container['couchdb.mapping_driver_chain.factory'] = $container->protect(function ($name) use ($container) {
            return new DriverChain;
        });

        $container['couchdb.add_mapping_driver'] = $container->protect(function (MappingDriver $mappingDriver, $namespace, $name = null) use ($container) {
            $container['couchdb.dms.options.initializer']();

            if (null === $name) {
                $name = $container['couchdb.dms.default'];
            }

            $driverChain = $container['couchdb.mapping_driver_chain.locator']($name);
            $driverChain->addDriver($mappingDriver, $namespace);
        });

        $container['couchdb.generate_psr0_mapping'] = $container->protect(function ($resourceMapping) use ($container) {
            $mapping = [];
            foreach ($resourceMapping as $resourceNamespace => $documentNamespace) {
                $directory = $container['psr0_resource_locator']->findFirstDirectory($resourceNamespace);
            if (!$directory) {
                throw new \InvalidArgumentException("Resources for mapping '$documentNamespace' could not be located; Looked for mapping resources at '$resourceNamespace'");
            }
                $mapping[$directory] = $documentNamespace;
          }

            return $mapping;
        });

        $container['couchdb.dm'] = function($container) {
            $dms = $container['couchdb.dms'];

            return $dms[$container['couchdb.dms.default']];
        };

        $container['couchdb.dm.config'] = function($container) {
            $configs = $container['couchdb.dms.config'];

            return $configs[$container['couchdb.dms.default']];
        };
    }

    /**
    * @param  \Pimple $container
    * @return array
    */
    protected function getCouchDbOdmDefaults(Container $container) {
    return array(
        'couchdb.proxies_dir' => __DIR__.'/../../../../../var/cache/doctrine/proxies',
        'couchdb.proxies_namespace' => 'CouchDBDoctrineProxy',
        'couchdb.proxy_namespace' => 'MyCouchDBProxyNS',
        'couchdb.auto_generate_proxies' => true,
        'couchdb.auto_generate_proxy_classes' => true,
        'couchdb.default_cache' => [
          'driver' => 'array',
        ],
        'couchdb.write_doctrine_metadata' => true,
        'couchdb.validate_doctrine_metadata' => true,
        'couchdb.uuid_generationbuffersize' => 20,
        'couchdb.all_or_nothing_flush' => true,
        'couchdb.lucene_handler_name' => '_fti',
        'couchdb.metadata_resolver' => null,
        'couchdb.class_metadata_factory_name' => '\Doctrine\ODM\CouchDB\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory',
        'couchdb.default_repository_class' => '\Doctrine\ODM\CouchDB\DocumentRepository',
        );
    }
}
```

I then registered both in `app.php`

```
$app->register(new DoctrineCouchDbServiceProvider());
$app->register(new DoctrineCouchDbOdmServiceProvider());
```

and added the couch db options and config into `config/prod.php`

```
$app['couchdb.options'] = [
    'dbname' => 'app_db',
    'type' => 'socket',
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'port' => 5984,
    'user' => null,
    'password' => null,
    'ip' => null,
    'logging' => true
];

$app['couchdb.dm.options'] = [
    'mappings' => [
        [
            'type' => 'annotation',
            'namespace' => 'Package\documents',
            'path' => __DIR__.'/../src/package/documents'
        ],
    ]
];
```

### My Documents

```
<?php
namespace Package\documents;

use Doctrine\ODM\CouchDB\Mapping\Annotations as CouchDB;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

// Have tried @CouchDB\Document as well

/**
 * @Document(repositoryClass="repositories\ZoneRepository")
 */
class Zone {
  /**
   * @Id(type="string")
   */
  protected $id;

  /**
   * @Field(type="string", indexed=true)
   */
  protected $slug;

  /**
   * @Field(type="string", jsonName="name", indexed=true)
   */
  protected $name;

  /** @Field(type="boolean", jsonName="enabled") */
  protected $enabled;
}
```

A long read, but hope it helps you figure out the issue.
Thanks for all the help

Comment: Let us have a look at your configuration of doctrine to proof your feeling about the possible reason of the error.

Comment: @llabball, I've updated the question. Thanks for the help.